# Getting Host Mesh working again in Scratch

Tags: software-installation, scratch

I just did an update of scratch (as advised [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=32056)), because of the performance problems when using it to interface with my PiFace (reported [here](http://scratch.mit.edu/forums/viewtopic.php?id=104467&p=1) and [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=12522)).

Unfortunately, now I don't see the 'Host mesh' menu item anymore when I shift-click the Share menu.

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it.

To re-enable Mesh, you have to go through a series of incantations which I've gleaned from various places.

1. You need to sudo-run Scratch, [otherwise](http://scratch.mit.edu/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=355156#p355156) you won't be able to save the changes. So from a terminal, you need to

   ```
   sudo /usr/bin/scratch
   ```
2. You need to access the 'secret' System.Browser, by shift-clicking the top half of the 'R' in the SCRATCH logo (screenshots, and the rest of this procedure, [here](http://scratch.mit.edu/forums/viewtopic.php?id=32046&p=1)).
3. In the menu that appears, select `Turn fill screen off`. This 'peels' the interface back a bit leaving a white border bottom and right. Click there and select `open...`
4. Then select `browser`. This opens the system browser. Here you should progressively navigate through `Scratch-UI-Panes -> ScratchFrameMorph -> menu/button actions -> addServerCommandsTo:`
5. This will give you an editable area beneath, where you should change the line `t2 <- true.` to `t2 <- false.`
6. At this point, all the other online instructions say you should 'right click and accept'. Right clicking did nothing for me, but if you have the editable pane selected, to the left you have a vertical scrollbar with a tiny `-` button a the top. If you click that, you see the `accept` option.
7. Enter your initials and hit `accept`, exit the system browser by clicking the `x` at top left.
8. Shift-click the R again and select `turn fill screen on`.

At this point, Mesh will work again. If you don't want to have to do this every time, you should Shift-click R one more time and select `save image for end-user`.

See also: http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Mesh

Comment: sudo /usr/bin/scratch only works in certain terminal emulators